# How do I make Travis-CI build Rust binaries using x86_64-pc-windows-msvc?

Tags: rust, travis-ci

I'm trying to build Windows binaries using Travis. I get a smaller binary size when building using the MSVC toolchain. Is there a way I can setup my .travis.yml to use the MSVC toolchain, or do I have to use shell scripts? If I have to use a script, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to .travis.yml should make Travis use the MSVC toolchain.

```
before_install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "windows" ]]; then rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc ; fi
```